# Modulo of 24 digit long integer?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I need to calculate the modulo of a 24 digit long integer ([IBAN checksum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_Bank_Account_Number)) but JS calculates wrong.

e.g.:
700901001234567890131400 % 97 = 90

but in JS (V8) it's 38.

How can I calculate the modulo in JS

Comment: What do you need the checksum for? The IBAN code is not an integer (leading zeroes count) and the control digit algorithm I know uses the 97 module in an entremely different way.

Comment: Oh, just read your link: *Any computer programming language or software package that is used to compute D mod 97 directly must have the ability to handle integers of more than 30 digits. In practice, this can only be done by software that either supports arbitrary-precision arithmetic or that can handle 220 bit (unsigned) integers,[Note 2] features that are often not standard. If the application software in use does not provide the ability to handle integers of this size, the modulo operation can be performed in a piece-wise manner (as is the case with the UN CEFACT TBG5 Javascript program).*

Comment: http://www.tbg5-finance.org/?ibandocs.shtml

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think the document you're linking to already says what you should do:

> If the application software in use does not provide the ability to handle integers of this size, the modulo operation can be performed in a piece-wise manner.
>
> Piece-wise calculation D mod 97 can be done in many ways. One such way is as follows:
>
> 1. Starting from the leftmost digit of D, construct a number using the first 9 digits and call it N.[Note 3]
> 2. Calculate N mod 97.
> 3. Construct a new 9-digit N by concatenating above result (step 2) with the next 7 digits of D. If there are fewer than 7 digits remaining in D but at least one, then construct a new N, which will have less than 9 digits, from the above result (step 2) followed by the remaining digits of D
> 4. Repeat steps 2–3 until all the digits of D have been processed
>      The result of the final calculation in step 2 will be D mod 97 = N mod 97.

Answer (score 2):

It might be harder than one can think.
It's quite tricky to ensure javascript handle number as integer (it often store them as float, but not always).

Others already made libraries to handle IBAN check in JS.
Take a look at https://github.com/arhs/iban.js for instance.

Answer (score 2):

The largest number that can be represented in javascript is 2^53 - 1. They are 64-bit floating point values. So the largest number is 9007199254740991.

A number greater than 9007199254740991 can not be caclcuted in normal way. So, to find the modulo of such large number you have to break it into pieces.

eg. 700901001234567890131400 can be broken into 700901001234567 and 890131400.

First find the modulo of 700901001234567.
700901001234567 % 97 = 13
Now join 13 infront of second number 13890131400 and find the modulo of this number
13890131400 % 97 = 90

Answer (score 0):

I came across this problem recently and this looks like what is solvable with Horner's method [https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Horner%27s_method]

```
/**
*  str is numeric.
*  MOD=97 is our use case
*  @return: an integer 0<=x<=97
**/
int getMod(String str, int MOD) {
    int remainder = 0;
    for(Character c : str.toCharArray()) {
        int value = Character.getNumericValue(c);
        remainder = 10*remainder + value;
        remainder %= MOD;
    }

    return remainder;
}
```

Unless I don't fully understand the problem, the code above should work.